# AngularJS Insert new Item in List works in JSfiddle but not in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, angularjs, html, visual-studio-2013

This is my first time coding in AngularJS. 
The funny thing is I put my code in JSfiddle and it works there but not in my Visual Studios:-

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3BJa/399/

Any help is appreciated.

I have a list of predefined Employees and I am trying to add a new item to the list:-

```
  function User(Name, Title, Company, Place) {
           this.Name = Name;
           this.Title = Title;
           this.Company = Company;
           this.Place = Place;


        }


        function UserController($scope) {
           $scope.userList = [
              new User("John Doe1", "Programmer", "xxx", "zzz, yyy"),
              new User("John Doe2", "Programmer", "xxx", "zzz, yyy")
           ];




           $scope.addNew = function (User) {
               $scope.userList.push(User);
               $scope.User = {}; //clear out person object
           }
        }
```

The issue is, everytime I add a new employee, The old userList is obtained which not only erases all edits to the list, but also never inserts into the list itself.

My HTML looks like:-

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-controller="UserController">
<b>Names</b>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="user in userList">
        {{user.Name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<div style="margin-top:40px"></div>
<b>Selected User</b>
<div class="row" style="margin-left:30px">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        Name: 
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:35px;">
        <input type=text data-ng-model="currentUser.Name">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:20px"></div>
<div class="row" style="margin-left:30px">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        Title: 
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:45px;">
        <input type=text data-ng-model="currentUser.Title">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:20px"></div>
<div class="row" style="margin-left:30px">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        Company: 
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:10px;">
        <input type=text data-ng-model="currentUser.Company">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:20px"></div>
<div class="row" style="margin-left:30px">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        Place:
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:35px;">
        <input type=text data-ng-model="currentUser.Place">
    </div>
</div>
```

The way I am attempting to add a new Item to my List:-

```
<div style="margin-left:40%">
<button data-ng-click="addNew(currentUser)" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Employee</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue. I am using AngularJS w/ .NET aspx page. The button is causing a postback which causes my data to refresh back to the pre-defined list.

To resolve it, I have used type tag in my button element and set it to button.

```
<button data-ng-click="" class="" type="button">
```

This resolved the issue w/ stopping the postback.